# XPath problem - Retrieving user by name (Mendix)

Tags: database, list, xpath, domain-model, mendix

1. I have Tasks entity, associated with Administration.Account entity (I use it to display a list of tasks with assigned users).
2. Tasks entity has a string parameter “Requester”, where I store names of users.

[image]

I created a microflow, which should retrieve an account of the user from the database, comparing his name with the name in the “Requester” parameter.

```
[Name = $Tasks.Requester]
```

The problem is, that I’m getting XPath error, and when I’m typing $Tasks. all available parameters belong to the Account entity, instead of the Tasks entity.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You must use slash (/) when constructing your XPath. So this should work in your case:

```
[Name = $Tasks/Requester]
```